# What does 'Mata de otra mata tú ves crecer' mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, letras-de-canciones

In the song ['Tesoro' by Ojos de Brujo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQx58BHuw0o) I came across the bolded phrase:

> En busca de mi tesoro
>   tú dale miel y ya bailará
>   aún sueño con mi cachorro
>   como mis colegas deben tener
>   ay con sus pequeños tesoros
>   **mata de otra mata tú ves crecer**
>   ahí abajo chilla el cachorro.

Can anyone make some sense of this?

Comment: My guess is there's a poetic connection between the plants, shrubs and trees in your garden, and the children you have, live for, feed, and watch grow and dance, etc.  Maybe someone who knows the group would know what sorts of themes they tend to sing about.  Keep in mind that in poetry things don't always march along in perfect syntax as they would in a book or article.

Comment: I included part of the lyrics and corrected many words, since they were a bit incorrect. By the way, great song from a fabulous band!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It literally means: You can see a bush growing from another bush.

Poetically, it means: You realise children are small versions of you.

Comment: ohh... thank you!